# How to access all children for Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models where a Project has many Goals and a Goal has many Tasks.

What is the best way to find a QuerySet containing all Tasks related to an individual Project?

**models.py** are per below:

```
class IndividualProject(models.Model):
    project = models.CharField(
        max_length = 64
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Project {self.project}"

class IndividualGoal(models.Model):
    goal = models.CharField(
        max_length = 64
        )

    project = models.ForeignKey(
        IndividualProject,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="projects",
        blank=True,
        null=True,        
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.goal}"

class IndividualTask(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField( 
        max_length = 256,
        blank=False,
        null=True,
        )

    goal = models.ForeignKey(
        IndividualGoal,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="goals",
        blank=False,
        null=True,
    )
```

I have tried using _set but have had no luck.

I would like to use a query where I select the Project and then select a specific Task.

Comment: `IndividualTask.objects.filter(goal__project=your_project)`

Answer (score 1):

You can start by getting the project from which you'll get all tasks using:-

```py
project = IndividualProject.objects.get(project='name_of_project')
```

You can then get all tasks related to that project though a goal using:-

```py
tasks = IndividualTask.objects.filter(goal__project=project)
```

That should give you a Queryset containing all the tasks.